# How to shell execute a file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried using the Process class as always but that didn't work. All I am doing is trying to run a Python file like someone double clicked it.

Is it possible?

EDIT:

Sample code:

```
string pythonScript = @"C:\callme.py";

string workDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName ( pythonScript );

Process proc = new Process ( );
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workDir;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = pythonScript;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "1, 2, 3";
```

I don't get any error, but the script isn't run. When I run the script manually, I see the result.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: Was that the System.Diagnostics.Process class? e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/06/01/146375.aspx

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't post the code.

Comment: Did you actually call proc.Start()?  It's not in the above code.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah I forgot to call Start. Stupid of me to overlook that one :)

Comment: @Joan: I say it's about time for you to take a break. Look away from your monitor.

Comment: You are right, I should do that. Fortunately I am gonna take off in less than an hour :)

Comment: +1 for dance2die's suggestion :P sounds like break time!

Comment: Joan, your code works perfectly for me with a freshly installed Python 3.0. I assume that there is a problem with your Python installation, presumably with the file associations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my code for executing a python script from C#, with a redirected standard input and output ( I pass info in via the standard input), copied from an example on the web somewhere. Python location is hard coded as you can see, can refactor.

```
    private static string CallPython(string script, string pyArgs, string workingDirectory, string[] standardInput)
    {

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
        Process process;

        string ret = "";
        try
        {

            startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\python25\python.exe");
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            if (pyArgs.Length != 0)
                startInfo.Arguments = script + " " + pyArgs;
            else
                startInfo.Arguments = script;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;


            process.Start();

            // write to standard input
            foreach (string si in standardInput)
            {
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(si);
            }

            string s;
            while ((s = process.StandardError.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                ret += s;
                throw new System.Exception(ret);
            }

            while ((s = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                ret += s;
            }

            return ret;

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            string problem = ex.Message;
            return problem;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to get the python location programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) should work. if it doesn't, would you post your code and the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot proc.Start() at the end.  The code you have should work if you call Start().