# Running execute file in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to shell execute a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749680/how-to-shell-execute-a-file-in-c)

How can i run an execute file in c# (by command line)?

and in addition, I want to save the output **and see** it on the screen?

Comment: There are many, many questions on SO that already address this.  Please check the "related" sidebar at bottom right.

Answer (score 2):

See the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

You use the StadardOutput (and optionally StandardError) to get the output and put it at the screen any way you want.

Comment: But I want to see the output on the screen during the running..

Comment: I think that is the default .

Comment: Yes, but if I see the output on the screen, I can't put it in text file.. I want put the output in text file and look on it in the screen both

Comment: Bokris, your question is closed now. Research it properly and if you can't get it to work then post a new question with focus on the output, show what you tried and explain what didn't work.